# How to store two click counters in variables and do some calculations with it - jquery

Tags: jquery

I've a "next" and "preview" div to click on. With the following code it is possible to store the counted clicks to a variable for each div. The alertboxes showing the results when clicking. So far so good.
But I don't know why any calculation with "var countNext" and "var countPrev" does not work!
The "var countResult" is always "0" clicking on #test div to alert the result.

```
var countNext = ($('#next').data('click_count') || 0);  
var countPrev = ($('#prev').data('click_count') || 0);  
var countResult = countNext - countPrev;  

  $('#next').on('click', function() {  
    countNext++;  
    alert(countNext);        
    });  

  $('#prev').on('click', function() {  
    countPrev++;         
    alert(countPrev);        
    });  

  $('#test').on('click', function() {  
    alert(countResult);        
    });
```

Do you know what's wrong with it?

Answer (score 0):

you need to recalculate the countResults every time the click happens

```
var countNext = ($('#next').data('click_count') || 0);  
var countPrev = ($('#prev').data('click_count') || 0);  
var countResult = countNext - countPrev;  

  $('#next').on('click', function() {  
    countNext++;  
    countResult = countNext - countPrev;
    alert(countNext);        
    });  

  $('#prev').on('click', function() {  
    countPrev++;       
    countResult = countNext - countPrev;  
    alert(countPrev);        
    });  

  $('#test').on('click', function() {  
    alert(countResult);        
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the only wrong with your code is don't store the counter data again in your `div`. you just get the value and use it but when you click the button you increment the variables but don't store it in your `div` data. So

```
$('#next').on('click', function() {  
   countNext++;  
   alert(countNext);        
   $('#next').data('click_count',countNext);
});
```

and same for `countPrev`

Answer (score 0):

Just incremeting the variable does'nt store it in the data() object :

```
$('#next, #prev').data('click_count', 0).on('click', function () {
    $(this).data('click_count', $(this).data('click_count') + 1);
});

$('#test').on('click', function () {
    alert($('#next').data('click_count') - $('#prev').data('click_count'));
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/ALFuY/1/)

Answer (score 0):

why not update the data attributes since you already have them instead of using global vars?

```
$('#next').on('click', function() { 
    var $this = $(this), new_click_count = $this.data('click_count') + 1;

    $this.data('click_count', new_click_count);  
    alert(new_click_count);        
});  

$('#prev').on('click', function() {  
    var $this = $(this), new_click_count = $this.data('click_count') + 1;

    $this.data('click_count', new_click_count);  
    alert(new_click_count);          
});  

$('#test').on('click', function() {  
    var next_count = $('#next').data('click_count'), prev_count = $('#prev').data('click_count'), countResult = next_count - prev_count;

    alert(countResult); 
});
```

and you can simplify that into:

```
$('#next, #prev').on('click', function() { 
        var $this = $(this), new_click_count = $this.data('click_count') + 1;

        $this.data('click_count', new_click_count);  
        alert(new_click_count);        
    });   

$('#test').on('click', function() {  
        var next_count = $('#next').data('click_count'), prev_count = $('#prev').data('click_count'), countResult = next_count - prev_count;

        alert(countResult); 
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Added a couple of amendments, but the main one was moving the calculation of the new result on click.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var countNext = 0;  
  var countPrev = 0;  

  $('#next').on('click', function() {  
    countNext++;  
    alert(countNext);        
    });  

  $('#prev').on('click', function() {  
    countPrev++;         
    alert(countPrev);        
    });  

  $('#test').on('click', function() {  
    var countResult = countNext - countPrev;
    alert(countResult);        
    }); 
});
```